# How to convert a field with 202008 to a date in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I am trying to convert a field that contains strings such as 202008, 202108 to a date field. I have tried the date() function, clicking on the measure and converting it to a date. I have also tried DATE(LEFT([Month],4)+"-"+RIGHT([Month],2)+"-01") but that will only return the year.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't work? It may be that you are converting it to a date properly, but only displaying the year. Hint, if you see the phase YEAR([YOUR DATE FIELD]) on some shelf, try right clicking on it and picking a different date granularity, such as MDY

Comment: You can also try the DATEPARSE() function

Answer (score 1):

Using Tableau Desktop 2021.1, when I change the data type from String to Date, Tableau translates the strings to 8/1/2020 and 8/1/2021.  If you are using an earlier version of Desktop, it is possible that this functionality is not present.

[image]

[image]

[image]

However, if changing the data type isn't working for you, the calculated field code you provided should actually work, you just need to change the date part from Year to Month/Day/Year using the Custom date part option.

[image]

[image]